# jQuery UI and nestedSortable droping on empty list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, nested-sortable

I am using jQuery UI and nestedSortable plugin (by ilikenwf on github) but I am having har time dropping the items inside empty lists. If you checkout the link below you have to find a sweet spot to dop the item. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Second question I set the maxLevels option to 2 but as you can see in the link it shows a 3rd level but doesn't drop it. Is there any other option that I don't know about? Or it should be like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.sortable').nestedSortable({
   handle: '.divHandle',
   items: 'li',
   toleranceElement: '> div',
   forcePlaceholderSize:true, 
   placeholder:"placeholder"

  });

 });




/*
 * jQuery UI Nested Sortable
 * v 2.0 / 29 oct 2012
 * http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable
 *
 * Depends on:
 *  jquery.ui.sortable.js 1.10+
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010-2013 Manuele J Sarfatti
 * Licensed under the MIT License
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

(function($) {

 function isOverAxis( x, reference, size ) {
  return ( x > reference ) && ( x < ( reference + size ) );
 }

 $.widget("mjs.nestedSortable", $.extend({}, $.ui.sortable.prototype, {

  options: {
   doNotClear: false,
   expandOnHover: 700,
   isAllowed: function(placeholder, placeholderParent, originalItem) { return true; },
   isTree: false,
   listType: 'ul',
   maxLevels: 2,
   protectRoot: true,
   rootID: null,
   rtl: false,
   startCollapsed: false,
   tabSize: 0,

   branchClass: 'mjs-nestedSortable-branch',
   collapsedClass: 'mjs-nestedSortable-collapsed',
   disableNestingClass: 'mjs-nestedSortable-no-nesting',
   errorClass: 'mjs-nestedSortable-error',
   expandedClass: 'mjs-nestedSortable-expanded',
   hoveringClass: 'mjs-nestedSortable-hovering',
   leafClass: 'mjs-nestedSortable-leaf',
   disabledClass: 'mjs-nestedSortable-disabled'
  },

  _create: function() {
   this.element.data('ui-sortable', this.element.data('mjs-nestedSortable'));

   // mjs - prevent browser from freezing if the HTML is not correct
   if (!this.element.is(this.options.listType))
    throw new Error('nestedSortable: Please check that the listType option is set to your actual list type');

   // mjs - force 'intersect' tolerance method if we have a tree with expanding/collapsing functionality
   if (this.options.isTree && this.options.expandOnHover) {
    this.options.tolerance = 'intersect';
   }

   $.ui.sortable.prototype._create.apply(this, arguments);

   // mjs - prepare the tree by applying the right classes (the CSS is responsible for actual hide/show functionality)
   if (this.options.isTree) {
    var self = this;
    $(this.items).each(function() {
     var $li = this.item;
     if ($li.children(self.options.listType).length) {
      $li.addClass(self.options.branchClass);
      // expand/collapse class only if they have children
      if ( ! $li.hasClass( self.options.collapsedClass ) && ( ! $li.hasClass( self.options.expandedClass ) ) ) {
       if (self.options.startCollapsed) $li.addClass(self.options.collapsedClass);
       else $li.addClass(self.options.expandedClass);
      }
     } else {
      $li.addClass(self.options.leafClass);
     }
    });
   }
  },

  _destroy: function() {
   this.element
    .removeData("mjs-nestedSortable")
    .removeData("ui-sortable");
   return $.ui.sortable.prototype._destroy.apply(this, arguments);
  },

  _mouseDrag: function(event) {
   var i, item, itemElement, intersection,
    o = this.options,
    scrolled = false;

   //Compute the helpers position
   this.position = this._generatePosition(event);
   this.positionAbs = this._convertPositionTo("absolute");

   if (!this.lastPositionAbs) {
    this.lastPositionAbs = this.positionAbs;
   }

   //Do scrolling
   if(this.options.scroll) {
    if(this.scrollParent[0] != document && this.scrollParent[0].tagName != 'HTML') {

     if((this.overflowOffset.top + this.scrollParent[0].offsetHeight) - event.pageY < o.scrollSensitivity) {
      this.scrollParent[0].scrollTop = scrolled = this.scrollParent[0].scrollTop + o.scrollSpeed;
     } else if(event.pageY - this.overflowOffset.top < o.scrollSensitivity) {
      this.scrollParent[0].scrollTop = scrolled = this.scrollParent[0].scrollTop - o.scrollSpeed;
     }

     if((this.overflowOffset.left + this.scrollParent[0].offsetWidth) - event.pageX < o.scrollSensitivity) {
      this.scrollParent[0].scrollLeft = scrolled = this.scrollParent[0].scrollLeft + o.scrollSpeed;
     } else if(event.pageX - this.overflowOffset.left < o.scrollSensitivity) {
      this.scrollParent[0].scrollLeft = scrolled = this.scrollParent[0].scrollLeft - o.scrollSpeed;
     }

    } else {

     if(event.pageY - $(document).scrollTop() < o.scrollSensitivity) {
      scrolled = $(document).scrollTop($(document).scrollTop() - o.scrollSpeed);
     } else if($(window).height() - (event.pageY - $(document).scrollTop()) < o.scrollSensitivity) {
      scrolled = $(document).scrollTop($(document).scrollTop() + o.scrollSpeed);
     }

     if(event.pageX - $(document).scrollLeft() < o.scrollSensitivity) {
      scrolled = $(document).scrollLeft($(document).scrollLeft() - o.scrollSpeed);
     } else if($(window).width() - (event.pageX - $(document).scrollLeft()) < o.scrollSensitivity) {
      scrolled = $(document).scrollLeft($(document).scrollLeft() + o.scrollSpeed);
     }

    }

    if(scrolled !== false && $.ui.ddmanager && !o.dropBehaviour)
     $.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets(this, event);
   }

   //Regenerate the absolute position used for position checks
   this.positionAbs = this._convertPositionTo("absolute");

   // mjs - find the top offset before rearrangement,
   var previousTopOffset = this.placeholder.offset().top;

   //Set the helper position
   if(!this.options.axis || this.options.axis !== "y") {
    this.helper[0].style.left = this.position.left+"px";
   }
   if(!this.options.axis || this.options.axis !== "x") {
    this.helper[0].style.top = this.position.top+"px";
   }

   // mjs - check and reset hovering state at each cycle
   this.hovering = this.hovering ? this.hovering : null;
   this.mouseentered = this.mouseentered ? this.mouseentered : false;

   // mjs - let's start caching some variables
   var parentItem = (this.placeholder[0].parentNode.parentNode &&
        $(this.placeholder[0].parentNode.parentNode).closest('.ui-sortable').length)
              ? $(this.placeholder[0].parentNode.parentNode)
              : null,
       level = this._getLevel(this.placeholder),
       childLevels = this._getChildLevels(this.helper);

   var newList = document.createElement(o.listType);

   //Rearrange
   for (i = this.items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    //Cache variables and intersection, continue if no intersection
    item = this.items[i];
    itemElement = item.item[0];
    intersection = this._intersectsWithPointer(item);
    if (!intersection) {
     continue;
    }

    // Only put the placeholder inside the current Container, skip all
    // items form other containers. This works because when moving
    // an item from one container to another the
    // currentContainer is switched before the placeholder is moved.
    //
    // Without this moving items in "sub-sortables" can cause the placeholder to jitter
    // beetween the outer and inner container.
    if (item.instance !== this.currentContainer) {
     continue;
    }

    // No action if intersected item is disabled 
    // and the element above or below in the direction we're going is also disabled
    if (itemElement.className.indexOf(o.disabledClass) !== -1) {
     // Note: intersection hardcoded direction values from jquery.ui.sortable.js:_intersectsWithPointer
     if (intersection === 2) {
      // Going down
      var itemAfter = this.items[i + 1];
      if (itemAfter && itemAfter.item[0].className.indexOf(o.disabledClass) !== -1){
       continue;
      }
      
     }
     else if (intersection === 1) {
      // Going up
      var itemBefore = this.items[i - 1];
      if (itemBefore && itemBefore.item[0].className.indexOf(o.disabledClass) !== -1){
       continue;
      }
     }
    }

    // cannot intersect with itself
    // no useless actions that have been done before
    // no action if the item moved is the parent of the item checked
    if (itemElement !== this.currentItem[0] &&
     this.placeholder[intersection === 1 ? "next" : "prev"]()[0] !== itemElement &&
     !$.contains(this.placeholder[0], itemElement) &&
     (this.options.type === "semi-dynamic" ? !$.contains(this.element[0], itemElement) : true)
    ) {

     // mjs - we are intersecting an element: trigger the mouseenter event and store this state
     if (!this.mouseentered) {
      $(itemElement).mouseenter();
      this.mouseentered = true;
     }

     // mjs - if the element has children and they are hidden, show them after a delay (CSS responsible)
     if (o.isTree && $(itemElement).hasClass(o.collapsedClass) && o.expandOnHover) {
      if (!this.hovering) {
       $(itemElement).addClass(o.hoveringClass);
       var self = this;
       this.hovering = window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(itemElement).removeClass(o.collapsedClass).addClass(o.expandedClass);
        self.refreshPositions();
        self._trigger("expand", event, self._uiHash());
       }, o.expandOnHover);
      }
     }

     this.direction = intersection == 1 ? "down" : "up";

     // mjs - rearrange the elements and reset timeouts and hovering state
     if (this.options.tolerance == "pointer" || this._intersectsWithSides(item)) {
      $(itemElement).mouseleave();
      this.mouseentered = false;
      $(itemElement).removeClass(o.hoveringClass);
      this.hovering && window.clearTimeout(this.hovering);
      this.hovering = null;

      // mjs - do not switch container if it's a root item and 'protectRoot' is true
      // or if it's not a root item but we are trying to make it root
      if (o.protectRoot
       && ! (this.currentItem[0].parentNode == this.element[0] // it's a root item
          && itemElement.parentNode != this.element[0]) // it's intersecting a non-root item
      ) {
       if (this.currentItem[0].parentNode != this.element[0]
           && itemElement.parentNode == this.element[0]
       ) {

        if ( ! $(itemElement).children(o.listType).length) {
         itemElement.appendChild(newList);
         o.isTree && $(itemElement).removeClass(o.leafClass).addClass(o.branchClass + ' ' + o.expandedClass);
        }

        var a = this.direction === "down" ? $(itemElement).prev().children(o.listType) : $(itemElement).children(o.listType);
        if (a[0] !== undefined) {
         this._rearrange(event, null, a);
        }

       } else {
        this._rearrange(event, item);
       }
      } else if ( ! o.protectRoot) {
       this._rearrange(event, item);
      }
     } else {
      break;
     }

     // Clear emtpy ul's/ol's
     this._clearEmpty(itemElement);

     this._trigger("change", event, this._uiHash());
     break;
    }
   }

   // mjs - to find the previous sibling in the list, keep backtracking until we hit a valid list item.
   var previousItem = this.placeholder[0].previousSibling ? $(this.placeholder[0].previousSibling) : null;
   if (previousItem != null) {
    while (previousItem[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'li' || previousItem[0].className.indexOf(o.disabledClass) !== -1 || previousItem[0] == this.currentItem[0] || previousItem[0] == this.helper[0]) {
     if (previousItem[0].previousSibling) {
      previousItem = $(previousItem[0].previousSibling);
     } else {
      previousItem = null;
      break;
     }
    }
   }

   // mjs - to find the next sibling in the list, keep stepping forward until we hit a valid list item.
   var nextItem = this.placeholder[0].nextSibling ? $(this.placeholder[0].nextSibling) : null;
   if (nextItem != null) {
    while (nextItem[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'li' || nextItem[0].className.indexOf(o.disabledClass) !== -1 || nextItem[0] == this.currentItem[0] || nextItem[0] == this.helper[0]) {
     if (nextItem[0].nextSibling) {
      nextItem = $(nextItem[0].nextSibling);
     } else {
      nextItem = null;
      break;
     }
    }
   }

   this.beyondMaxLevels = 0;

   // mjs - if the item is moved to the left, send it one level up but only if it's at the bottom of the list
   if (parentItem != null
    && nextItem == null
    && ! (o.protectRoot && parentItem[0].parentNode == this.element[0])
    &&
     (o.rtl && (this.positionAbs.left + this.helper.outerWidth() > parentItem.offset().left + parentItem.outerWidth())
      || ! o.rtl && (this.positionAbs.left < parentItem.offset().left))
   ) {

    parentItem.after(this.placeholder[0]);
    if (o.isTree && parentItem.children(o.listItem).children('li:visible:not(.ui-sortable-helper)').length < 1) {
     parentItem.removeClass(this.options.branchClass + ' ' + this.options.expandedClass)
         .addClass(this.options.leafClass);
    }
    this._clearEmpty(parentItem[0]);
    this._trigger("change", event, this._uiHash());
   }
   // mjs - if the item is below a sibling and is moved to the right, make it a child of that sibling
   else if (previousItem != null
      && ! previousItem.hasClass(o.disableNestingClass)
      &&
      (previousItem.children(o.listType).length && previousItem.children(o.listType).is(':visible')
       || ! previousItem.children(o.listType).length)
      && ! (o.protectRoot && this.currentItem[0].parentNode == this.element[0])
      &&
      (o.rtl && (this.positionAbs.left + this.helper.outerWidth() < previousItem.offset().left + previousItem.outerWidth() - o.tabSize)
       || ! o.rtl && (this.positionAbs.left > previousItem.offset().left + o.tabSize))
   ) {

    this._isAllowed(previousItem, level, level+childLevels+1);

    if (!previousItem.children(o.listType).length) {
     previousItem[0].appendChild(newList);
     o.isTree && previousItem.removeClass(o.leafClass).addClass(o.branchClass + ' ' + o.expandedClass);
    }

          // mjs - if this item is being moved from the top, add it to the top of the list.
          if (previousTopOffset && (previousTopOffset <= previousItem.offset().top)) {
           previousItem.children(o.listType).prepend(this.placeholder);
          }
          // mjs - otherwise, add it to the bottom of the list.
          else {
     previousItem.children(o.listType)[0].appendChild(this.placeholder[0]);
    }

    this._trigger("change", event, this._uiHash());
   }
   else {
    this._isAllowed(parentItem, level, level+childLevels);
   }

   //Post events to containers
   this._contactContainers(event);

   //Interconnect with droppables
   if($.ui.ddmanager) {
    $.ui.ddmanager.drag(this, event);
   }

   //Call callbacks
   this._trigger('sort', event, this._uiHash());

   this.lastPositionAbs = this.positionAbs;
   return false;

  },

  _mouseStop: function(event, noPropagation) {

   // mjs - if the item is in a position not allowed, send it back
   if (this.beyondMaxLevels) {

    this.placeholder.removeClass(this.options.errorClass);

    if (this.domPosition.prev) {
     $(this.domPosition.prev).after(this.placeholder);
    } else {
     $(this.domPosition.parent).prepend(this.placeholder);
    }

    this._trigger("revert", event, this._uiHash());

   }


   // mjs - clear the hovering timeout, just to be sure
   $('.'+this.options.hoveringClass).mouseleave().removeClass(this.options.hoveringClass);
   this.mouseentered = false;
   this.hovering && window.clearTimeout(this.hovering);
   this.hovering = null;

   $.ui.sortable.prototype._mouseStop.apply(this, arguments);
   
   var pid = $(this.domPosition.parent).parent().attr("id");
   var sort = this.domPosition.prev ? $(this.domPosition.prev).next().index() : 0;
   
   if(!(pid == this._uiHash().item.parent().parent().attr("id") && 
    sort == this._uiHash().item.index())) {
    this._trigger("relocate", event, this._uiHash());
   }

  },

  // mjs - this function is slightly modified to make it easier to hover over a collapsed element and have it expand
  _intersectsWithSides: function(item) {

   var half = this.options.isTree ? .8 : .5;

   var isOverBottomHalf = isOverAxis(this.positionAbs.top + this.offset.click.top, item.top + (item.height*half), item.height),
    isOverTopHalf = isOverAxis(this.positionAbs.top + this.offset.click.top, item.top - (item.height*half), item.height),
    isOverRightHalf = isOverAxis(this.positionAbs.left + this.offset.click.left, item.left + (item.width/2), item.width),
    verticalDirection = this._getDragVerticalDirection(),
    horizontalDirection = this._getDragHorizontalDirection();

   if (this.floating && horizontalDirection) {
    return ((horizontalDirection == "right" && isOverRightHalf) || (horizontalDirection == "left" && !isOverRightHalf));
   } else {
    return verticalDirection && ((verticalDirection == "down" && isOverBottomHalf) || (verticalDirection == "up" && isOverTopHalf));
   }

  },

  _contactContainers: function(event) {

   if (this.options.protectRoot && this.currentItem[0].parentNode == this.element[0] ) {
    return;
   }

   $.ui.sortable.prototype._contactContainers.apply(this, arguments);

  },

  _clear: function(event, noPropagation) {

   $.ui.sortable.prototype._clear.apply(this, arguments);

   // mjs - clean last empty ul/ol
   for (var i = this.items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var item = this.items[i].item[0];
    this._clearEmpty(item);
   }

  },

  serialize: function(options) {

   var o = $.extend({}, this.options, options),
    items = this._getItemsAsjQuery(o && o.connected),
       str = [];

   $(items).each(function() {
    var res = ($(o.item || this).attr(o.attribute || 'id') || '')
      .match(o.expression || (/(.+)[-=_](.+)/)),
        pid = ($(o.item || this).parent(o.listType)
      .parent(o.items)
      .attr(o.attribute || 'id') || '')
      .match(o.expression || (/(.+)[-=_](.+)/));

    if (res) {
     str.push(((o.key || res[1]) + '[' + (o.key && o.expression ? res[1] : res[2]) + ']')
      + '='
      + (pid ? (o.key && o.expression ? pid[1] : pid[2]) : o.rootID));
    }
   });

   if(!str.length && o.key) {
    str.push(o.key + '=');
   }

   return str.join('&');

  },

  toHierarchy: function(options) {

   var o = $.extend({}, this.options, options),
    sDepth = o.startDepthCount || 0,
       ret = [];

   $(this.element).children(o.items).each(function () {
    var level = _recursiveItems(this);
    ret.push(level);
   });

   return ret;

   function _recursiveItems(item) {
    var id = ($(item).attr(o.attribute || 'id') || '').match(o.expression || (/(.+)[-=_](.+)/));
    if (id) {
     var currentItem = {"id" : id[2]};
     if ($(item).children(o.listType).children(o.items).length > 0) {
      currentItem.children = [];
      $(item).children(o.listType).children(o.items).each(function() {
       var level = _recursiveItems(this);
       currentItem.children.push(level);
      });
     }
     return currentItem;
    }
   }
  },

  toArray: function(options) {

   var o = $.extend({}, this.options, options),
    sDepth = o.startDepthCount || 0,
       ret = [],
       left = 1;

   if (!o.excludeRoot) {
    ret.push({
     "item_id": o.rootID,
     "parent_id": null,
     "depth": sDepth
    });
    left++
   }

   $(this.element).children(o.items).each(function () {
    left = _recursiveArray(this, sDepth + 1, left);
   });

   ret = ret.sort(function(a,b){ return (a.left - b.left); });

   return ret;

   function _recursiveArray(item, depth, left) {

    var right = left + 1,
        id,
        pid;

    if ($(item).children(o.listType).children(o.items).length > 0) {
     depth ++;
     $(item).children(o.listType).children(o.items).each(function () {
      right = _recursiveArray($(this), depth, right);
     });
     depth --;
    }

    id = ($(item).attr(o.attribute || 'id')).match(o.expression || (/(.+)[-=_](.+)/));

    if (depth === sDepth + 1) {
     pid = o.rootID;
    } else {
     var parentItem = ($(item).parent(o.listType)
            .parent(o.items)
            .attr(o.attribute || 'id'))
            .match(o.expression || (/(.+)[-=_](.+)/));
     pid = parentItem[2];
    }

    if (id) {
      ret.push({"item_id": id[2], "parent_id": pid, "depth": depth});
    }

    left = right + 1;
    return left;
   }

  },

  _clearEmpty: function(item) {
   var o = this.options;

   var emptyList = $(item).children(o.listType);

   if (emptyList.length && !emptyList.children().length && !o.doNotClear) {
    o.isTree && $(item).removeClass(o.branchClass + ' ' + o.expandedClass).addClass(o.leafClass);
    emptyList.remove();
   } else if (o.isTree && emptyList.length && emptyList.children().length && emptyList.is(':visible')) {
    $(item).removeClass(o.leafClass).addClass(o.branchClass + ' ' + o.expandedClass);
   } else if (o.isTree && emptyList.length && emptyList.children().length && !emptyList.is(':visible')) {
    $(item).removeClass(o.leafClass).addClass(o.branchClass + ' ' + o.collapsedClass);
   }

  },

  _getLevel: function(item) {

   var level = 1;

   if (this.options.listType) {
    var list = item.closest(this.options.listType);
    while (list && list.length > 0 &&
                     !list.is('.ui-sortable')) {
     level++;
     list = list.parent().closest(this.options.listType);
    }
   }

   return level;
  },

  _getChildLevels: function(parent, depth) {
   var self = this,
       o = this.options,
       result = 0;
   depth = depth || 0;

   $(parent).children(o.listType).children(o.items).each(function (index, child) {
     result = Math.max(self._getChildLevels(child, depth + 1), result);
   });

   return depth ? result + 1 : result;
  },

  _isAllowed: function(parentItem, level, levels) {
   var o = this.options,
    maxLevels = this.placeholder.closest('.ui-sortable').nestedSortable('option', 'maxLevels'); // this takes into account the maxLevels set to the recipient list

   // mjs - is the root protected?
   // mjs - are we nesting too deep?
   if ( ! o.isAllowed(this.placeholder, parentItem, this.currentItem)) {
     this.placeholder.addClass(o.errorClass);
     if (maxLevels < levels && maxLevels != 0) {
      this.beyondMaxLevels = levels - maxLevels;
     } else {
      this.beyondMaxLevels = 1;
     }
   } else {
    if (maxLevels < levels && maxLevels != 0) {
     this.placeholder.addClass(o.errorClass);
     this.beyondMaxLevels = levels - maxLevels;
    } else {
     this.placeholder.removeClass(o.errorClass);
     this.beyondMaxLevels = 0;
    }
   }
  }

 }));

 $.mjs.nestedSortable.prototype.options = $.extend({}, $.ui.sortable.prototype.options, $.mjs.nestedSortable.prototype.options);
})(jQuery);
```

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

ul {
 list-style:none;
}

.taskListColumn{
 float:left;
 padding: 0px 0px;
 margin: 5px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bolder;
 max-width: 370px !important;
}

.headerTaskListColumn{
 padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px;

}

.taskListElement{
 color: black;
 margin:10px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.sortable div{
 cursor: grab;
}

.taskListElementContent{
 padding: 10px 20px;
}

li ul{
 padding-bottom:20px;
}

 .placeholder {
  outline: 1px dashed #4183C4;
  float:left;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
 }
.taskListContent{
 padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h3>Sortable inside the oother sorable</h3>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <ul class="sortable row flex-nowrap">
  <li class="taskListColumn p-2 col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 bg-dark rounded"><div class="headerTaskListColumn bg-dark divHandle rounded-top ">Basslik 1</div>

  </li>
  
  <li class="taskListColumn p-2 col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 bg-dark rounded"><div class="headerTaskListColumn bg-dark divHandle rounded-top">Baslik2</div>
   <ul>
    <li class="taskListElement">
     <div class="taskListElementContent divHandle rounded bg-light">
      Some sub-item content1
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="taskListElement">
     <div class="taskListElementContent divHandle rounded bg-light">
      Some sub-item content2
     </div>
    </li>
    <li class="taskListElement">
     <div class="taskListElementContent divHandle rounded bg-light">
      Some sub-item content3
     </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
   
  </li>
  <li class="taskListColumn p-2 col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 rounded bg-dark"><div class="headerTaskListColumn divHandle">Baslik3</div>

  </li>

 </ul>
</div>
```